# Undo saved file after close

Tags: php, undo, zend-studio

I've lost a very important file, because when I'm working on it, and I decide to test something there, I've deleted a very important part in it, and then my PC shuts down, so now I have missing a very important part from there. That was a `.php` file, and I'm using Zend Studo.

Is it possible to undo last operation after save, if I close the file?

Sorry for such a question, I understand, that this not from programming sphere, but I don't know what to do.

Comment: You can recreate it from a version control, or at least the last backup. If you don't use a vcs, you maybe realize now, what they are good for.

Comment: It was local files, and i'm working on windows.

Comment: Next time, back up your work and comment out stuff you don't want instead of deleting it.

Comment: So is it impossible ?

Comment: down votes for asking a application question not a programming one.

Comment: @Dagon: No reason to downvote a good question on the wrong website; just flag it for migration.

Answer (score 2):

in zend studio, right click on file in the explorer view, click "Compare With "> "Local History"

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans has a thing called Local History, which is basically a history of previous versions. I don't know Zend Studio, but it seems it has [something similar](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio/local_history.htm).

Just like in Netbeans, you can compare versions from different dates, restore sections, etc., [take a look here](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio/comparing_files.htm).

Comment: It can only restore deleted files, not undo operations.

Comment: @Syom According to the documentation, it works almost exactly the same as in Netbeans; you can compare versions from different dates, restore sections, etc. Take a look: http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio/comparing_files.htm

Comment: Eclipse also has this feature. Even though I commit frequently, I would not use an IDE without this feature.